# Is there a reason why I cannot get a 'pet' to follow me but when just a normal cube part it works with the exact same script? Roblox studio-Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

This exact code works on a part with a 4,4,4 sizing. I have tried multiple things like adding wields, groups, union. I even changed the sizing to fit the testing. The code should basically make the cube follow the player around when player is walking around. This code works but doesn't function when the same script is parented to the model I want.

```
local pet = script.Parent

function givePet (player)
    if player then
        local character = player.Character
        if character then
            local humRootPart = character.HumanoidRootPart
            local newPet = pet:Clone ()
            newPet.Parent = character

            local bodyPos = Instance.new("BodyPosition", newPet)
            bodyPos.MaxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge, math.huge, math.huge)

            local bodyGyro = Instance.new("BodyGyro", newPet)
            bodyGyro.MaxTorque = Vector3.new(math.huge, math.huge, math.huge)

            while wait() do
                bodyPos.Position = humRootPart.Position + Vector3.new(2, 2, 3)
                bodyGyro.CFrame = humRootPart.CFrame
            end
        end
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        givePet(player)
    end)
end)
```

[image: This is the picture of my model that it does not work in]

This is the picture of my model that it does not work in

Any advice to solve this issue would be appreciated. Thanks! :D

Comment: Doublecheck that there aren't any anchored parts in the model hierarchy

Comment: That was the problem, everything was anchored and then i had to ungroup it all and make a Union so it all stayed together and will now have to readjust the rotation as it is at an angle. Thanks so much for your help, I knew it was going to be something so simple. :D

Comment: By any chance do you know which part of the script you can change to make the rotation change because i'm not sure how to?